Intellij Idea + Gradle: Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build
I have a simple test case. Windows 10.
Java file - proj\src\main\kotlin\cothonaty\ksandbobx\Sandbox.java:
package cothonaty.ksandbobx;

public class Sandbox {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("asd");
    }
}

The project in Intellij in set initially with Gradle as a Kotlin project.
What I am trying to understand is next:
When I press the green triangle run button near by the main method, it runs the standard "Application" configuration which outputs the next log:
0:56:34: Executing ':Sandbox.main()'...

> Task :checkKotlinGradlePluginConfigurationErrors
> Task :compileKotlin NO-SOURCE
> Task :compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :classes UP-TO-DATE

> Task :Sandbox.main()
asd

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.

You can use '`--warning-mode all`' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 279ms
3 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 1 up-to-date
0:56:35: Execution finished ':Sandbox.main()'.

What I need to do is to run the app without any deprecated options.
Here is my kts
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.9.23"
}

group = "cothonaty.ksandbobx"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation(kotlin("test"))
}

tasks.test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
kotlin {
    jvmToolchain(21)
}
java {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java {
                setSrcDirs(listOf("src/main/kotlin"))
            }
        }
    }
}

The main goal - I need to run the "Application" configuration with the flag --warning-mode all.
However, I cannot find where I should put the --warning-mode all option in the "Application" type of configuration.
I understand that I can use terminal (or cmd in my case) to perform gradle run --warning-mode all. However, it starts downloading some chain toolkit with 192 MB size that I don't really need on my PC as I can freely run without any downloads now from the "Application" configuration.
Please advise how I can run the blue Application configuration with the flag --warning-mode all.
Please do not advise to use terminal/cmd to perform a separate run. I need to run it with the flag from the Intellij Idea embedded environment, not from the separate gradle process. I understand that Intellij for sure runs its own Gradle, but I need to put the flat --warning-mode all into this Intellij's Application run configuration.
I tried to add and run the Gradle configuration, however, in this case, I need to edit my kts what I dont want to do by principles as Intellij Idea able to run it without any edits in the kts.
https://imgur.com/a/KdwgD4s
Everything I described in the post

Modifying the call of a main method
You can modify the arguments passed to the command to run the Java main method by choosing "Modify run configuration..." when you choose the green triangle.
However, I do not think this will help you identify the deprecated Gradle features in use, which appears to be your goal.
When you run a main method like that I believe you are running a pseudo Gradle task that IntelliJ has created itself. Thus there isn't really a Gradle task you can run to execute that main method and pass the --warning-mode all arguments. The options given are to modify the java command call.
Modifying the call of a Gradle task
This is not a problem though, because you can add --warning-mode all to any Gradle task call and it will output the deprecation warnings. I recommend help as this is the simplest task.
To run help, or any other Gradle task, with specific arguments in IntelliJ, right-click on it in the Gradle tool window and choose "Modify run configuration...". In there you can add the arguments and thus view the deprecation warnings without using the terminal.

Thank you. However, running a gradle task requires editing the kts file which makes me confused as native intellij gradle run does not require editing.

No, you can run a Gradle task from the Gradle tool window (defaults to the right-hand side). You are trying to find what's deprecated in your Gradle setup so you are going to have to interact with it on some level
